# Titanium: Animate an element in a ListItem/ ListView

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I want to animate an element in a `ListItem`

For example, consider the following simple `ListView`:

```
<ListView>
    <Templates>
        <ItemTemplate name="foo">
            <View layout="vertical">
                <Label color="red" id="label" bindId="bExampleLabel"/>
                <Button onClick="onClickButton">Click Me to make the label go blue</Button>
            </View>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </Templates>

    <ListSection id="exampleListSection">
        <ListItem template="foo" bExampleLabel:text="Example 1"></ListItem>
        <ListItem template="foo" bExampleLabel:text="Example 2"></ListItem>
    </ListSection
</ListView>
```

and the following script:

```
function onClickButton(e) {
    var item = $.exampleListSection.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
    item.bExampleLabel = {
        color: 'blue'
    };
    $.exampleListSection.updateItemAt(e.itemIndex, item);
}
```

The above XML code simply has a `ListView` which contains 2 `ListItem`, which each contains a label and a button. When you click the button, it makes the label go blue.

However I want it so that it **animates** it to blue.

Usually this is done like so:

```
$.elementId.animate({
    color: 'blue'
});
```

However, I do not know how to do this in the context of a `ListItem` as you cannot seem to access the objects directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't animate ListItem in listView, you can change only the item properties accessing with bindId

> templates : Dictionary
>
> Contain key-value pairs mapping a style name (key) to an ItemTemplate (value).
> This property cannot be changed once a window has been opened.

if you want to set animation in listing use TableView, and you can do what you want with TableViewRow

Comment: Is there anyway to at least interact with the objects directly? How about using a require statement?

Comment: I just found out that you cannot have a require statement. But none the less, is it not possible to access an element directly?

Comment: yes you can't use require statement with ListView, you access only on the item returned by getItemAt or ListView.data[sectionId][itemId].

Comment: use TableView and require you custom TableViewRow